# Google podcast app, how to trigger play programmatically

Tags: android

I have an android app where I have a button, and when I click on that button, I want the google podcast to start playing the current podcast, but I cannot figure out what the event is called.

I.E, I have a working one for a podcast app celled podcastrepublic that looks like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent("podcastrepublic.playback.action.play");
intent.setPackage("com.itunestoppodcastplayer.app");
context.sendBroadcast(intent);
context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(intent));
```

does anyone know how to solve it for google podcast app?

Comment: Normally you do this by using a MIME type for the data and allowing the user to choose which app he wants to use (or even set a default for that type).  You don't normally code in every app specifically, there's hundreds.

Comment: Thanks Gabe, I haven't thought about using MIME type. However this is not a app for the public, is an app only used by me to optimize a process, hence I only need to hardcode it for one app :)